# How to stop transition and keep current translate

Tags: javascript, css

following is my code, I wanna stop transtion **but keep its current translateY**, but  following code stop transition and set translateY 0, I expect a way can get current translateY when transition

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--mobile friendly-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
  <style>
    .it {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: pink;
      transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="it">
</div>

<script type="module">
  var it = document.querySelector(".it")
  setTimeout(() => {
    it.style.transform = "translateY(500px)"
  }, 100)

  setTimeout(() => {
    it.style.transform = null
  }, 1000)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method I don't know if it will satisfy you

```html
  <style>
    .it {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: pink;
      transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
    }

    .it-class {
      transform: translateY(500px) ;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="it">
</div>
<button>stop</button>
<script>
  var it = document.querySelector(".it")
  const button = document.querySelector("button")
  button.onclick = () => {
    it.classList.toggle('it-class')
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, use getBoudingRectClient().y and window.scrollY can get element abs pos y in document;

so get parent abs_pos_y and element abs_pos_y to get current element pos y from parent top border(rel_pos_y),

cur_translateY = rel_pos_y - element.offsetTop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--mobile friendly-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
  <style>
    .c {
      position: relative;
      border: 5px solid black;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .it {
      margin-top: -200px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: pink;
      transition: 2s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="c">
  <div class="it">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="module">
  var it = document.querySelector(".it")

  // offsetTop don't calc translateY, so use following get element abs pos y in document
  var getPos = (e) => {
    var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect()
    return {
      x: rect.x + window.scrollX,
      y: rect.y + window.scrollY
    }
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    it.style.transform = "translateY(300px)"
  }, 100)
  //
  setTimeout(() => {
    var c = document.querySelector(".c")
    var cy = getPos(c).y
    console.log(`cy:${cy}`)
    var iy = getPos(it).y
    console.log(`iy:${iy}`)
    it.style.transform = `translateY(${iy - cy - it.offsetTop}px)` // iy - cy is element dist from parent top border, - it.offsetTop get translateY
  }, 800)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```